# Which scala compiler plugins are available?

Tags: scala, plugins, scalacl

I stumbled across the ScalaCL project and its [compiler plugin](http://code.google.com/p/scalacl/wiki/ScalaCLPlugin) that has an awesome loop optimizer.

This made me wonder:

**Which compiler plugins are available for scala?**

Plugins need not be performance improving plugins; any type of plugin is eligible for this list.

(I have done Google searches but the SNR is low for this query.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few plugins are linked from [this thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Scala-compiler-plugin-documentation-td3228423.html) on the mailing list ([autoproxy](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=275135), [browse](https://github.com/harrah/browse), [enhanced strings](https://github.com/jrudolph/scala-enhanced-strings), [avro](http://code.google.com/p/avro-scala-compiler-plugin/)).

From the Scala team, there is the existing [delimited continuations](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2096) plugin, and a current effort toward an [effect system](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/ScalaDays+2011+Resources#ScalaDays2011Resources-LightweighteffecttypesforScala) plugin.

Documentation on writing a plugin is [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140).

Answer (score 3):

There also exists a compiler plugin for generation functional lenses in scalaz: https://github.com/gseitz/Lensed for more details see here: http://groups.google.com/group/scalaz/browse_thread/thread/a9334c5741b67d55

Comment: I had read about the lenses plugin but forgotten about it. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the miniboxing plugin, for optimizing generics: [scala-miniboxing.org](http://scala-miniboxing.org).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plugin written by [Eiríkr Åsheim](https://twitter.com/#!/d6) that optimizes generic numeric code (runtime + compiler plugin) :
https://github.com/azavea/numeric